# PostgreSQL - Create a database view for multiple tables with a multi-to-multi relationship

Tags: postgresql, database-design

In my PostgreSQL database, I have a "item" table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
  "objectId" text NOT NULL,
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone,
  item_name text,
  is_parent boolean,
  CONSTRAINT "ITEM_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("objectId")
);
```

The table contains both parent items and child items with the "is_parent" column declaring it.

Another table defines a multi-to-multi relationship where a parent item can have multiple child items, and so does a child item.

```
CREATE TABLE item_pa_ch_rel
(
  "objectId" text NOT NULL,
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone,
  item_pa character(10),   -- foreign key of item.objectId for a parent item
  item_ch character(10),   -- foreign key of item.objectId for a child item
  CONSTRAINT item_pa_ch_rel_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("objectId")
);
```

I would like to create a database view which would join the two tables on item.objectId and contain parent_objectId, parent_item_name, child_objectId, and child_item_name:

```
parent_objectId, parent_item_name, child_objectId, child_item_name
```

Comment: Join them how? You describe columns of a result, but not how the output rows are a function of the input rows. PS Looks like this might be a faq. Please always google many clear, concise, specific phrasings of your question/problem/goal/issue & read many answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive CTE - Get descendants (many-to-many relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47780183/recursive-cte-get-descendants-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: My case is much simplier than the post you suggested. I don't think it is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I came into an answer:

```
DROP VIEW vw_test;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_test AS 
 SELECT t1.item_name AS p_item_name,
    t2."createdAt",
    t2."updatedAt",
    t3.item_name AS c_item_name,
    t2."objectId"
   FROM item t1 INNER JOIN item_pa_ch_rel t2 on t1."objectId" = t2.item_pa::text
   INNER JOIN item t3 on t2.item_ch::text = t3."objectId";

ALTER TABLE vw_test
  OWNER TO gc;
```